# MYSQL PHP Return Order by Best Matches From multiple words in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm making an Ajax search where the user can search with multiple words like this '**pa a s**' using PHP MYSQL AJAX

Consider this table for example:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+
| id |   name    |   city    | country  |  type   |   status   |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+
|  1 | howard    | eugene    | usa      | person  | publish    |
|  2 | john      | paris     | france   | person  | publish    |
|  3 | marco     | lisbon    | portugal | person  | publish    |
|  4 | paula     | madrid    | spain    | person  | publish    |
|  5 | josé      | barcelona | spain    | person  | publish    |
|  6 | hanna     | berlin    | germany  | person  | publish    |
|  7 | paolo     | torino    | italy    | person  | publish    |
|  8 | laurence  | monaco    | france   | company | publish    |
|  9 | giovanni  | bergamo   | italy    | company | publish    |
| 10 | manuel    | porto     | portugal | person  | publish    |
| 11 | maurizio  | beijing   | china    | company | publish    |
| 12 | mario     | são paulo | brazil   | person  | notpublish |
+----+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+
```

In this table I only want results of the type **person** and status **publish**

The Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE type="person" 
AND status="publish" 
AND (name LIKE "%pa%" OR city LIKE "%pa%" 
    OR country LIKE "pa%" 
    OR name LIKE "%a%" 
    OR city LIKE "%a%" 
    OR country LIKE "%a%" 
    OR name LIKE "%s%" 
    OR city LIKE "%s%" 
    OR country LIKE "s%" 
)
```

Through a loop it explodes the string based on space and makes this sql code, so basically it tries to find the 3 words in the 3 columns (9 searchs).

```
$words = explode(" ", 'pa a s'); //'pa'; 'a'; 's';
```

The question is, I want to Order by the number of finds. For example:
The string 'pa' is found in the column 'name' with the id: 4,7
The string 'pa' is found in the column 'city' with the id: 2
The string 'pa' is found in the column 'country' with the id: 4,5

The string 'a' is found in the column 'name' with the id: 1,3,4,6,7,10
The string 'a' is found in the column 'city' with the id: 2,4,5
The string 'a' is found in the column 'country' with the id: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10

The string 's' is found in the column 'name' with the id: 5
The string 's' is found in the column 'city' with the id: 2,3
The string 's' is found in the column 'country' with the id: 1,4,5

The order should be:

```
The ID 4 was matched: 6 Times
The ID 5 was matched: 5 Times
The ID 2 was matched: 4 Times
The ID 1 was matched: 3 Times
The ID 3 was matched: 3 Times
The ID 7 was matched: 3 Times
The ID 6 was matched: 2 Times
The ID 10 was matched: 2 Times
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: In the Order by, i cant order by the number of finds

Comment: anyone can help me ?